# Crop image, make transparent sub region and background ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, crop, transparent, region

I want to crop an image (area1), then make white a particular sub area(area2) of the cropped image and finally make the background transparent.

I'm able to get my desired output in the following 3 separate commands.

```
convert input.jpg -crop 908x391+21+545 out1.jpg   'crop image (area1)
convert out1.jpg -fuzz 100% -fill '#ffffff' -region 908x28+4+33 -opaque white out2.jpg  'make blank particular region (area2)
convert out2.jpg -bordercolor "#0019ff" -border 4x4 -transparent white output.png       'make all white background transparent
```

But when I try to join the 3 commands in a single one like below, in the output the area2 still appears and background is not transparent.

```
convert input.jpg -crop 908x391+21+545 -fuzz 100% -fill '#ffffff' -bordercolor "#0019ff" -border 4x4 -region 908x28+25+578 -transparent white output.png
```

How can I make this in a single command? Thanks

**Update**

```
convert input.jpg \
\( -clone 0 -crop 908x391+21+545  +repage -region 908x28+4+33 -fill white \
-colorize 100 +region -resize 908x681! -bordercolor "#f019ff" -border 4x4 \
-repage 1842x689+0+0   \) \
\
\( -clone 0 -crop 908x391+21+4444 +repage -region 908x28+4+33 -fill white \
-colorize 100 +region -resize 908x681! -bordercolor "#f019ff" -border 4x4 \
-repage 1842x689+926+0 \) \
-delete 0 -flatten -resize 1180 -transparent white OOUUTT.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick 6, try this (if Imagemagick 7 replace convert with magick), using new line \ to make it more readable.

```
convert input.jpg -crop 908x391+21+545 +repage \
-region 908x28+4+33 -fill white -colorize 100 +region \
-bordercolor "#0019ff" -border 4x4 -transparent white \
output.png
```

Or as one long command line:

```
convert input.jpg -crop 908x391+21+545 +repage -region 908x28+4+33 -fill white -colorize 100 +region -bordercolor "#0019ff" -border 4x4 -transparent white output.png
```

For example using a gradient input:

```
convert -size 1500x1500 gradient: -crop 908x391+21+545 +repage -region 908x28+4+33 -fill white -colorize 100 +region -bordercolor "#0019ff" -border 4x4 -transparent white output.png
```

[image]

Or alternately compositing a transparent region over your cropped image:

```
convert -size 1500x1500 gradient: -crop 908x391+21+545 +repage \
\( -size 908x28 xc:none \) \
-alpha on -channel rgba -geometry +4+33 -compose copy -composite \
output2.png
```

Comment: Many thanks fmw42. It works perfect with first solution you shared. I need to crop 2 images from input image and I inserted your solution  in my original script and I got my desired output. Please see my update above. Thanks so much.